# Product catalog in views that is hierarchical but not mutually exclusive

Tags: views

I am trying to get views create a product catalog in taxonomy that is hierarchical but categories are not mutually exclusive.  For instance, lets say my hierarchy looks like this:

```
+---Color 
|   +---Red 
|   \---Blue 
|       +---Sky Blue 
|       +---Navye Blue 
|
+---Shape 
|   +---Cirlce 
|   \---Quadrilateral
|       +---Rectangle
|       +---Square
|
+---Size 
|   +---1" 
|   +---2" 
|   +---3" 
|   +---4"
```

When browsing the view I want visitors to be able to drill down through the categories while still having the other categories exposed to be filtered without requiring the user to select size before shape or vice versa.  The site that is inspired me the most in this project is this: [McMaster-Carr](http://www.mcmaster.com/#standard-washers/=ouo9no).  As you can see in that link, just browsing through the washer section is quite an adventure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I'm looking for here is a faceted search, which I can use through the [Facet API module](https://drupal.org/project/facetapi).  It looks like [this](http://www.photoshare.org/images/search/grid/health)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to achieve this with an exposed filter in views, 'Has taxonomy terms' or 'Has taxonomy terms (with depth)' for example. Use this as an exposed filter (dropdown with multiple select) in a page display. 
In the advanced settings in views you can choose to expose the form in a block. You can add this to the left sidebar and activate 'autosubmit'. So everytime they change something the results get filtered.

Since dropdown is not that nice, I would try on basis of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208997/drupal-7-creating-a-taxonomy-filter-using-checkboxes to change it to checkboxes.